# How to use associated constants to define the length of an array?

Tags: function, rust, traits

I've got a trait which represents an entity that can be sent through UDP sockets:

```
pub trait ToNetEnt {
    const NET_SIZE: usize;

    fn from_net(data: &[u8]) -> Self;
    fn to_net(&self) -> &[u8];
}
```

Though there is an associated constant `NET_SIZE`, I couldn't use it in methods:

```
pub fn req<T: ToNetEnt>(&self) -> T {
    let buf: [u8; T::NET_SIZE];
}
```

because it causes this error:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `NET_SIZE` found for type `T` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:23
   |
10 |         let buf: [u8; T::NET_SIZE];
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ associated item not found in `T`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `NET_SIZE`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `ToNetEnt`
```

Can I use an associated constant in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At time of writing this is not possible. But let's first fix your code:

```
pub fn req<T: ToNetEnt>(&self) -> T {
    let buf: [u8; <T as ToNetEnt>::NET_SIZE];
    ...
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This should be the right syntax, but does not compile at the moment:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: ToNetEnt` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:6:19
  |
6 |     let buf: [u8; <T as ToNetEnt>::NET_SIZE];
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ToNetEnt` is not implemented for `T`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where T: ToNetEnt` bound
```

which is simply a **wrong** error message to the problem. See [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29646#issuecomment-366146434):

> [U]sing an associated const as an array size does not appear to work:
>
> ```
> pub trait Can {
>     const SIZE: usize;
> }
>
> fn f<T: Can>(t: T) {
>     // error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: Can` is not satisfied
>     let x = [0u8; <T as Can>::SIZE];
> }
> ```
>
> There error message is clearly wrong, so this is either a bug in `rustc` or unimplemented functionality resulting in a bogus error message.

You can workaround this when defining the `const NET_SIZE` in your struct directly.

You can read more about this at the GitHub issue for this specific bug: [Array lengths don't support generic type parameters (#43408)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43408).

Comment: This is correct; a lot of work has been put into associated consts and const generics and it's hard to keep track, but `T::NET_SIZE` works just fine outside of the array declaration.

Comment: I think everyone is looking forward for const generics. This will simplify so many things...

Comment: Cool; I'm also not sure about your first statement - IMO `T::NET_SIZE` should work just as fine as `<T as ToNetEnt>::NET_SIZE` and outside of array lengths it worked for me in the playground.

Comment: Since neither of them are working, I expected `<T as ToNetEnt>::NET_SIZE` to be more clear. The linked comment on GitHub also uses this syntax, which has strengthened my opinion. I almost always use `<T as Bar>::` in associative types. Is this not needed in const associative types?

Comment: I only mean that it *might* work, but who knows? We can only be certain when it lands.

Answer (score 0):

To access an associated constant, you need to explicitly say which trait it is coming from, using this slightly cumbersome syntax: `<T as ToNetEnt>::NET_SIZE`.

Comment: This does not work at the moment. See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: True, it doesn't work as a compile time constant. It does work as the [general syntax for accessing associated constants](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1c8d952c9bed040bf58d39b6d28880a2&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).